# How to use the = in an angular variable

Tags: html, angular

I need to do something like that:

```
<app-popover #popName texto="{{'texto'='errorName1' | translate}}" ></app-popover>
<app-popover #popName texto="{{'texto'='errorName2' | translate}}" ></app-popover>
<app-popover #popName texto="{{'texto'='errorName3' | translate}}" ></app-popover>
```

But it returns an error

I have to send this to another html where the text will be printed, but since the code is reused and it is a translator what I use I have to be able to use different variable names:

```
<ng-template #popContent let-greeting="greeting">{{"texto"}}!</ng-template>
```

Comment: Are these components siblings?Parent child?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you catch it in the TS/JS and use a switchcase?

```
switch (this.texto) {
  case this.error1:
    this.texto = this.error1;
    break;
  case this.error2:
    this.texto = this.error2;
    break;
}
```

Alternate option is to use an if/else statement.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I think your question is a little bit unclear.
If I guess right what you want to do you should:
1. bind the property to the error like [textto]=error
2. accept the input via @input in your app-popover component
3. translate the text directly in the app-popover component

I think this way is clearer and more easy to reuse since you can just use an array and loop if you get more than 3 errors without having to go back. I think this approach should also get rid of your error because I think the line texto="{{'texto'='errorName1' | translate}}" is too prone to errors.